# Update shapefile attributes after update of data source

Tags: shapefile, update, data-source

In a project the data is stored in a relational database (so it could be moved to PostgreSQL) for presentation in a web repository to be presented in diagrams, tables, etc. During the last months columns with spatial information were added to some entities and the idea of presenting these over a map came up. GeoServer and PostGIS are now set up (with the PostGIS database being seperate from the repositories DB on another server), delivering a shapefile to the clients. There will be updates to the dataset of the web app about once a week. Therefore the .dbf file of the shapefile needs an update too. Now, I could write a trigger which in its final consequence creates a new/updated shapefile - but: What is an established way of handling & automating this case, where data is stored in one DB and the shapefile is held in another?

Comment: This task description is confusing.  Shapefiles don't get loaded into PostGIS, the shapefile's data is converted into a PostgreSQL table, with PostGIS geometry. If the spatial data is modified in the database, then both the source's `.shp` and `.shx` are no longer valid, and if the row order is compromised, none of the shapefile elements are valid. For referential integrity purposes, any edit in the database should result in a new shapefile snapshot being created.

Comment: @Vince Thank you for your comment. I updated the description to make it clear that the repository's DB is seperate (even on another server) from the newly set up GIS-system's DB.

Comment: A "shapefile" is a specific file-based format (and an ancient one, at that). You appear to be using it as a generic reference to spatial data in a database. This is damaging the quality of your question. It is a common GIS beginner antipattern to separate the spatial components from the other core data. I've witnessed this cause system failure many times. Geometry is principal component to any GIS, and should not be shunted to the side. There are many potential mechanisms for populating a publication database to firewall a production DB from a DMZ website.